# Variable definition in 'sh -c'

Tags: shell, variable

I tried to define a variable in a 'sh -c' command string:

```
sh -c "TMP=??; echo $TMP;"
```

Nothing was printed.

Why can't I define a variable in a 'sh -c' string?

Comment: It works perfectly in my environment. What OS are you using, and which version of bash?

Comment: @mrc02_kr  It would only work if `$TMP` is `??` before executing the line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sh -c 'TMP=??; echo $TMP;'
```

When using double quotes the parameter expansion occurs when the command line is built i.e. the shell does not see

```
TMP=??; echo $TMP;
```

as its parameter but

```
TMP=??; echo ;
```

if `$TMP` is empty in the calling shell environment.

Comment: Also note that if you expect `??` to be printed as opposed to the names of the non-hidden files in the current directory that consist of two characters, you'll need `sh -c 'TMP=??; echo "$TMP"'`

Comment: I realized I hadn't left appreciation. Thank you it helped a lot :D

Answer (score 9):

```
sh -c 'TMP=??; echo "$TMP"'
```

With *double* quotes around the `sh -c` code, the `$TMP` is expanded by the interactive shell *before* the `sh -c` code executes.  With single quotes, `$TMP` will be expanded inside the `sh` shell. (I've also properly quoted the `$TMP` variable expansion for `echo`).

Single quotes protects a string from variable expansions.

If you do not intend the `??` to be treated as a filename globbing pattern inside the `sh -c` script, then use

```
sh -c 'TMP="??"; echo "$TMP"'
```